# How can I return country-codes in d3 using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Dear fellow Programmers,

I've got a question regarding d3 and JQuery. In the code below i'm using data to color a d3 world map I acquired from http://datamaps.github.com/scripts/datamaps-all.js. I need to make sure that when the user clicks on one of the countries, it returns the country code of that country (3 letters, for example: NLD) so I can use it for other functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$("#container1").datamap({
 scope: 'world',
 done: $(function(datamap) {
  datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
     var countryData = mapData[geography.id];
}),
geography_config: {
 borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
 highlightBorderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
 popupTemplate: _.template([
   '<div class="hoverinfo">',
   '<% if (data.name) { %> <strong><%= data.name %></strong><br/><% } %>',
       '<% if (data.GDP) { %>',
       'GDP per capita: <strong><%= data.GDP %><strong><br/> <% } %>',
       '</div>'
       ].join('') )
},
fills: {
 A: '#fdd0a2',
 B: '#fdae6b',
 C: '#fd8d3c',
 D: '#f16913',
 E: '#d94801',
 F: '#a63603',
 G: '#7f2704',
 defaultFill: 'grey' 
},
data: {
  "QAT": {
    "name": "Qatar",
    "fillKey": "G",
    "GDP": "140649.2"
  },
  "": {
    "name": "Gambia",
    "fillKey": "A",
    "GDP": "1630.5"
  },
  "LUX": {
    "name": "Luxembourg",
    "fillKey": "G",
    "GDP": "98459.5"
  },
  "SGP": {
    "name": "Singapore",
    "fillKey": "F",
    "GDP": "82763.0"
  },
....
```

Comment: what are you getting in geography variable?

Comment: It shows the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectAll' of undefined.

Comment: And when i console.log(datamap) it shows: function: (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/joserocha3/pen/ZObMqz) for a working example, click on a country and you will get an alert with the country name and ISO code. It is not using jquery but it should help you figure out what variables to use in the DONE callback.

You should probably use http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js instead of http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps-all.js. If there is a reason you are using datamaps-all.js please let me know.

**Javascript used in the DONE callback:**

```
done: function(datamap) {
  datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
    var message = geography.properties.name + ' has a country code of ' + geography.id;
    console.log(message);
    alert(message);
  });
}
```

**HTML referencing the script I am using:**

```
<script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
```

**Check your popupTemplate property as well, here is mine:**

```
popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
  return data && data.GDP ? 
    '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' + geo.properties.name + '</strong><br/>GDP per capita: <strong>' + data.GDP + '</strong></div>' : 
    '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' + geo.properties.name + '</strong></div>';
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your feedback!